# how to convert string protofield to number in wireshark lua dissector

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm now developing a wireshark dissector with lua. There has one filed means length in packet which is encoded by `ASCII`, and it's displayed as string in dissection tree and display filter, like this

```
MyProto.length == "0237"
```

In fact, I want it to be number, so i can use  "great than" or "less than" in display filter.

So, how to do it in lua dissector?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to turn a string into a number? If so it's very easy!

```
print(type(tonumber("0237")))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my want. There is several field types in wireshark lua dissector, what i want is convert one to another, like `uint16 string` and so on

Comment: @pfip I don't get what you mean, how can you check what types they are?